# SDE State ID with Python

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning

I have created a Python script which compresses an ArcSDE geodatabase and now I would like to view the State ID after the compress.  Is there a way with Python I can get this info?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `state_id` from the `SDE_states` table in your database. You could do a simple call to that table after your compress, something along the lines of:

```
sql = "SELECT state_id FROM SDE_states WHERE name = "DEFAULT"
```

You  could use [pyodbc](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/GettingStarted) probably, but many other solutions out there to connect to and query databases from Python.

Comment: You could also use ArcSDESQLExecute and loop over the results if you want to stay within arcpy. Here's the link - http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z0000007z000000

Comment: The states table doesn't have a name column, but the versions table does. Naming or the tables varies by RDBMS and release.  There may also be more than one version named "DEFAULT" (and it could be owned by different users e.g. 'DBO' in SQL-Server, or any user with a user-schema geodatabase in Oracle)